# I am having weird router problems

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

Recently, I bought an internet connection for 300 Mbps, and I bought an Archer C60 along with it, not knowing that the maximum speed for WAN and Ethernet ports was only 100 Mbps. Also, I have an older Archer C5 gigabit router, and when I plug the internet connection wire from my ISP into Archer C5, it is showing an orange light on the globe symbol, indicating that there is no incoming internet connection. But it is working allright with Archer C60. Please help me to resolve this issue.

***P.S Until about one month ago, the Archer C5 was used for another connection at another address. So, I did a reset of the router. I got an internet connection briefly for about 5 minutes, and again its back to showing orange light on the globe.***

Comment: If your Internet access is via a DOCSIS cable modem, you have to power-cycle the modem after switching out what is connected to its Ethernet port. Otherwise the modem will never realize it needs to start talking to the new router.

Comment: I didn't understand most of what you said. But one thing that I can definitely say is that I do not have a modem, only a router. I have a cable that brings internet, provided by the ISP. And a router that I talked about

Comment: At this point you should probably contact your ISP's technical support team.